# Use Where with .Select Linq

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

I have a scenario where i have to use .Select with where in LINQ.
Below is my query.

```
List<DTFlight> testList = _ctrFlightList.Select(i => new DTFlight() { AirLineName = i.AirLineName,ArrivalDate = i.ArrivalDate }).ToList();
```

I want ti use where(add condition) to this query.

Please Help...
Thanks.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I suggest you this use of Where :

```
List<DTFlight> testList = _ctrFlightList.
    Where(ctrFlight => ctrFlight.Property > 0).
    Select(i => new DTFlight() { AirLineName = i.AirLineName, ArrivalDate = i.ArrivalDate }).ToList();
```

Where returns a IEnumerable, so you can apply your Select on it.

Answer (score 7):

Simply add the `Where` before the `Select`:

```
List<DTFlight> testList =
    _ctrFlightList.Where(<your condition>)
                  .Select(i => new DTFlight() { AirLineName = i.AirLineName,
                                                ArrivalDate = i.ArrivalDate })
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the problem?

```
List<DTFlight> testList = _ctrFlightList.Where(p => p.ArrivalDate > DateTime.Now).Select(i => new DTFlight() { AirLineName = i.AirLineName,ArrivalDate = i.ArrivalDate }).ToList();
```

for example... What condition do you need?